# For which $z \in \Bbb{C}$ does this series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

How can I determine for which $z\in \Bbb{C}$ the following series converges?

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}$$

I've tried the root and ratio test with no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $|z|<1$, the  summand is $<2|z|^n$ in absolute value for $n$ large enough (because the denominator $\to 1$), so there the series converges.

The summands (hence also the convergence and limiting function) are invariant under the substitution $z\leftarrow \frac1z$:
$$\frac{(1/z)^n}{1+(1/z)^{2n}} =\frac{z^{2n}\cdot(1/z)^n}{z^{2n}\cdot(1+(1/z)^{2n})}=\frac{z^n}{z^n+1}$$
Therefore the series converges also for $|z|>1$.

For $|z|=1$,  the summands are all $\ge\frac12$ in absolute value (or even undefined), so no convergence

Comment: Thank you. Can you please elaborate on how you obtained the inequality in the case that $|z| > 1$?

Comment: @iwriteonbananas The proof becomes simpler by observing the symmetry of the expression.